# Tkinter add Widgets (a Button) to a new second Frame

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I created a Frame, gave it a menubar. Works just fine. The purpose of the entry in the menubar is to open a new frame, in which u can change some settings. The creation of the new Window works also. However I can't create widgets on the new created window. I tried it with a Button and got a 
TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed

I tried to google it and found [Cannot invoke button command: application has been destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645716/cannot-invoke-button-command-application-has-been-destroyed) which didn't quite helped me.
Further I found a solution were u have to create a parent class (which inherrits from Frame) and than create all other Frames within it, but on the first view it looked pretty complicated. Especially because the creation of the second window seems to work in the first place.

I know this is probably a really basic question, so thanks in advance for your time

```
def perfSettings():
    perfFrame = Tk(className=" Performanz Einstellungen")
    perfFrame.configure(bg='#F2F2F2')
    perfFrame.geometry("300x300")
    perfFrame.mainloop()

    btn = Button(master=perfFrame, text='Speichern', command=myPerfSettingValue.getValues, width=37)
    btn.pack()
#    Button(perfFrame, text='Abbrechen', command=perfFrame.destroy, width=37).grid(row=0 ,column=1 )

class perfSettingsValue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bvhSteps = 0

    def getValues(self):
        pass

#Hauptfenster
root = Tk(className="BoneMapping & SkeletonEstimation")
root.configure(bg='#F2F2F2')
root.geometry("1300x600")

myPerfSettingValue = perfSettingsValue()

menubar = Menu(root)
sdmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
sdmenu.add_command(label="Performanz", command=perfSettings)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Einstellungen',menu=sdmenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
```

Comment: Don't create second Tk instance. Use Toplevel instead and mainloop should be at the end for this one. You should read more about what mainloop is and what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem here is that you are trying to add a button after starting the `mainloop` which effectively blocks the execution of the program. The error you are getting is because the line that adds the button gets executed after the window has been closed.

Your problem will be solved if you modify your function like this:

```
def perfSettings():
    perfFrame = Tk(className=" Performanz Einstellungen")
    perfFrame.configure(bg='#F2F2F2')
    perfFrame.geometry("300x300")


    btn = Button(master=perfFrame, text='Speichern', command=myPerfSettingValue.getValues, width=37)
    btn.pack()
    perfFrame.mainloop()
```

This is not the only problem though. Instead of creating a new instance of Tk, you should create a new Toplevel instance, which will, in your case, act just as a Tk instance, but have a lot less tendency to cause trouble.

Finally, you should consider reading on the object oriented approach to designing tkinter applications. There are far too many variants of that to be appropriately elaborated here but I certainly recommend you take the effort to learn to use one of them. It will make your code more comprehensible and maintainable. My usual approach is to create a class that inherits from Toplevel or Tk for every type of window I am going to use.

Comment: This example shows incorrect use of `Tk` and then explains that it's incorrect. I think this answer would be better if you showed a proper working example that did not create a second instance of `Tk`. I think it will be very tempting for a beginner to see the code and copy it without reading all the way through the answer.